# Eph. 2:6 and raised us up together, and made us sit together in the heavenly places in Christ Jesus

Tags: jesus, revelation, ephesians, pauline-epistles

We know that Jesus is sitting at the right hand of God.
In Eph.2:6 it says that we, believers of Christ, made us sit together in the heavenly places in Christ Jesus. Does it mean we are also sitting where Christ is seated?
What is " sit together in the heavenly places in Christ Jesus" really mean?

Comment: Good question. Up-voted +1. By baptism, we are dead with Christ and Paul says 'I am crucified with Christ'. This text follows on from those experiences.

Comment: @Giselle This might help. I'm paraphrasing Revelation 20:6 here: “Blessed and holy is the one who has a part in the first resurrection [baptism into Christ]; over these [Christians], the second death [spiritual death] has no power, but they [Christians] will be priests of God and of Christ [all Christians are priests and royalty: 1 Peter 2:9] and *will reign with Him for a 1,000 years* [until Christ’s return].” In Christ, we are reigning with Him now. We were dead to God before our death, burial, and resurrection through baptism. The 1,000 years is symbolic of the amount of time until the end.

Answer (score 1):

Ephesians 1:3
English Standard Version

> Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the **heavenly places**,

heavenly realms.
ἐπουρανίοις (epouraniois)
Adjective - Dative Neuter Plural
Strong's 2032: From epi and ouranos; **above the sky**.

The Greek word, by itself, does not carry a sense of precise location.

Ephesians 2:6
English Standard Version

> and raised us up with him and **seated** us with him in the heavenly places **in** Christ Jesus,

New International Version

> And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with him in the heavenly **realms** in Christ Jesus,

Does it mean we are also sitting where Christ is seated?

No, not necessarily. Pulpit explains:

> As God placed Jesus at his right hand in heaven, so he has placed his people with him in heavenly places; i.e. places where the privileges of heaven are dispensed, where the air of heaven is breathed

Comment: Some translate the word as 'the heavenlies'. See [The Englishman's Greek New Testament](https://archive.org/details/englishmansgreek00step/page/502/mode/2up).

Answer (score 1):

**EPH 2:6** *And hath raised us up together, and made us sit together in heavenly places in Christ Jesus:*

The word translated “together” (synegeirō) here was used three times - here in Ephesians, and also in Colossians.

**COL 2:12** *Buried with him in baptism, wherein also ye are risen with him*

**COL 3:1***If ye then be risen with Christ*

It is describing our union with Christ in being “quickened” (Ephesians 2:5), “raised” (this verse), and seated “in heavenly places” (this verse). None of these things are possible on our own. It is only through our union with Christ that any of this is attainable.

Made us “sit” (sygkathizō), used in this verse, “raised” (Ephesians 1:20 and this verse), and “quickened” (Ephesians 2:1 and 5) are all in the aorist tense. This indicates something that God has already accomplished in Christ, not something that is off in the future.

So this verse (Ephesians 2:6) is a present reality for believers. To understand what this means will be determined somewhat by your doctrinal foundation. Especially on your understanding of the ‘spiritual’ aspect of Christianity. And here ‘views’ differ.

Nevertheless the reality of what these verses are clearly stating can not be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibly relevant "sitting" passages. It seems clear to me that at a minimum, Paul would have us understand that we are being given an incredibly privileged and honored position with Christ. Based on other passages, some measure of co-regency or co-judging seems also be implied.

**Ex. 11:5**

> the firstborn of the Pharaoh who sits on his throne

(Pharaoh letting his firstborn sit on his throne as co-regent? cf. Ex. 12:29)

**Ruth 4:1-2** -leaders of Bethlehem sit down together to decide an important matter

**1 Sam. 2:8**

> He lifts the needy from the garbage heap To seat them with nobles, And
> He gives them a seat of honor

**1 Kings 2:19**

> the king stood to meet her, bowed to her, and sat on his throne; then
> he had a throne set up for the king’s mother, and she sat on his right

(cf. Neh. 2:6 where Artaxerxes' wife sat next to him)

**Job 36:7**

> He does not withdraw His eyes from the righteous, But with kings on
> the throne He has seated them forever, and they are exalted

**Ps. 61:6-7**

> You will prolong the king’s life; His years will be like generations.
> He will sit enthroned before God forever;

**Ps. 110:1**

> The Lord says to my Lord: “Sit at My right hand...

(cf. Matt. 22:44)

**Ps. 113:7-8**

> He lifts the needy from the garbage heap, To seat them with
> noblemen...

**Pr. 31:23**

> Her husband is known in the gates, When he sits among the elders of
> the land

**Matt. 19:28**

> you who have followed Me, in the regeneration when the Son of Man will
> sit on His glorious throne, you also shall sit upon twelve thrones,
> judging the twelve tribes of Israel

**Matt. 20:21**

> Say that in Your kingdom these two sons of mine shall sit, one at Your
> right, and one at Your left

**Luke 22:69**

> the Son of Man will be seated at the right hand of the power of God

**Rev. 3:21**

> The one who overcomes, I will grant to him to sit with Me on My
> throne, as I also overcame and sat with My Father on His throne

**Rev. 20:4**

> Then I saw thrones, and they sat on them, and judgment was given to
> them. And I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded because of
> their testimony of Jesus and because of the word of God, and those who
> had not worshiped the beast or his image, and had not received the
> mark on their foreheads and on their hands; and they came to life and
> reigned with Christ for a thousand years